# Random forest class_weight and sample_weight parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a class imbalance problem and been experimenting with a weighted Random Forest using the implementation in scikit-learn (>= 0.16).

I have noticed that the implementation takes a `class_weight` parameter in the tree constructor and `sample_weight` parameter in the fit method to help solve class imbalance. Those two seem to be multiplied though to decide a final weight.

I have trouble understanding the following:

- In what stages of the tree construction/training/prediction are those weights used? I have seen some papers for weighted trees, but I am not sure what scikit implements.
- What exactly is the difference between `class_weight` and `sample_weight`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

RandomForests are built on Trees, which are very well documented. Check how Trees use the sample weighting:

- [User guide on decision trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification) - tells exactly what algorithm is used
- [Decision tree API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) - explains how sample_weight is used by trees (which for random forests, as you have determined, is the product of class_weight and sample_weight).

As for the difference between `class_weight` and `sample_weight`: much can be determined simply by the nature of their datatypes. `sample_weight` is 1D array of length `n_samples`, assigning an explicit weight to each example used for training. `class_weight` is either a dictionary of each class to a uniform weight for that class (e.g., `{1:.9, 2:.5, 3:.01}`), or is a string telling sklearn how to automatically determine this dictionary.

So the training weight for a given example is the product of it's explicitly named `sample_weight` (or `1` if `sample_weight` is not provided), and it's `class_weight` (or `1` if `class_weight` is not provided).

Comment: You are right about DT as the base classifier. I am also interested in how those weights are used during training (e.g. deciding impurity of a decision node etc.) and during prediction.

Comment: Check out the documentation for `sample_weight` under the `fit()` method: [Decision tree API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier)

Comment: Although it is not crystal clear, I think everything will be clearer when I digest the material in the links :)

Answer (score 1):

If we look at [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L195-L653), `RandomForestClassifier` is sub-classed from `ForestClassifier` class, which in turn is sub-classed from `BaseForest` class and the `fit()` method is actually defined the `BaseForest` class. As OP pointed out, the interaction between `class_weight` and `sample_weight` determine the sample weights used to fit each decision tree of the random forest.

If we inspect [`_validate_y_class_weight()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L769-L800), [`fit()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L395-L399) and [`_parallel_build_trees()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L168-L192) methods, we can understand the interaction between `class_weight`, `sample_weight` and `bootstrap` parameters better. In particular,

- if `class_weight` is passed to the `RandomForestClassifier()` constructor but no `sample_weight` is passed to `fit()`, `class_weight` is used as the sample weight
- if both `sample_weight` and `class_weight` are passed, then they are multiplied together to determine the final sample weights used to train each individual decision tree
- if `class_weight=None`, then `sample_weight` determines the final sample weights (by default, if None, then samples are equally weighted).

The relevant part in the source code may be summarized as follows.

```py
from sklearn.utils import compute_sample_weight

if class_weight == "balanced_subsample" and not bootstrap:
    expanded_class_weight = compute_sample_weight("balanced", y)
elif class_weight is not None and class_weight != "balanced_subsample" and bootstrap:
    expanded_class_weight = compute_sample_weight(class_weight, y)
else:
    expanded_class_weight = None

if expanded_class_weight is not None:
    if sample_weight is not None:
        sample_weight = sample_weight * expanded_class_weight
    else:
        sample_weight = expanded_class_weight
```

With `bootstrap=True`, observations are randomly selected for individual trees trained, which is done via the `sample_weight` argument of [`fit()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L168-L192) whose relevant (abridged) code looks like the following.

```py
if bootstrap:
    if sample_weight is None:
        sample_weight = np.ones((X.shape[0],), dtype=np.float64)

    indices = check_random_state(tree.random_state).randint(X.shape[0], n_samples_bootstrap)
    sample_counts = np.bincount(indices, minlength=X.shape[0])
    sample_weight *= sample_counts

    if class_weight == "balanced_subsample":
        sample_weight *= compute_sample_weight("balanced", y, indices=indices)
```