# class_weight hyperparameter in Random Forest change the amounts of samples in confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I'm currently working on a Random Forest Classification model which contains 24,000 samples where 20,000 of them belong to `class 0` and 4,000 of them belong to `class 1`. I made a `train_test_split` where test_set is `0.2` of the whole dataset (around 4,800 samples in `test_set`). Since I'm dealing with imbalanced data, I looked at the hyperparameter `class_weight` which is aimed to solve this issue.

The problem I'm facing the moment I'm setting `class_weight='balanced'` and look at the `confusion_matrix` of the training set I'm getting something like that:

`array([[13209,   747],
       [ 2776,  2468]])`

As you can see, the lower array corresponds to `False Negative = 2776` followed by `True Positive = 2468`, while the upper array corresponds to `True Negative = 13209` followed by `False Positive = 747`. The problem is that the amount of samples belong to `class 1` according to the `confusion_matrix` is `2,776 (False Negative) + 2,468 (True Positive)` which sums up to `5,244 samples` belong to `class 1`. This doesn't make any sense since the whole dataset contains only 4,000 samples which belongs to `class 1` where only 3,200 of them are in the `train_set`. It looks like the `confusion_matrix` return a `Transposed` version of the matrix, because the actual amount of samples belong to `class 1` in the `training_set` should sum up to 3,200 samples in `train_set` and 800 in `test_set`. In general, the right numbers should be 747 + 2468 which sums up to 3,215 which is the right amount of samples belong to `class 1`.
Can someone explain me what happens the moment I'm using `class_weight`? Is it true that the `confusion_matrix` returns a `transposed` version of the matrix? Am I looking at it the wrong way?
I have tried looking for an answer and visited several questions which are somehow similar, but none of them really covered this issue.

Those are some of the sources I looked at:

[scikit-learn: Random forest class_weight and sample_weight parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805192/scikit-learn-random-forest-class-weight-and-sample-weight-parameters)

[How to tune parameters in Random Forest, using Scikit Learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107820/how-to-tune-parameters-in-random-forest-using-scikit-learn)

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11564/how-does-class-weights-work-in-randomforestclassifier

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244630/difference-between-sample-weight-and-class-weight-randomforest-classifier

[using sample_weight and class_weight in imbalanced dataset with RandomForest Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424685/using-sample-weight-and-class-weight-in-imbalanced-dataset-with-randomforest-cla)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducing the toy example from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html):

```python
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [1, 1, 1, 0]

tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
(tn, fp, fn, tp)
# (0, 2, 1, 1)
```

So, the reading of the confusion matrix you have provided seems to be correct.

> Is it true that the confusion_matrix returns a transposed version of
>   the matrix?

As the above example showed, no. But a very easy (and innocent-looking) mistake can be that you have interchanged the *order* of the `y_true` and `y_pred` arguments, which does matter; the result would be indeed a transposed matrix:

```python
# correct order of arguments:
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
# array([[0, 2],
#        [1, 1]])

# inverted (wrong) order of the arguments:
confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_true)
# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 1]])
```

It is impossible to say if this is the reason from the info you have provided, which is a good reminder of why you should always provide your actual code, rather than a verbal description of what you *think* your code is doing...

Comment: That was indeed my problem, I figured that 2 minutes before you posted the answer, thank you very much for the explanation as well, the problem is now fixed. Cheers.