# Is there any way to use complex survey weights in Random Forest models in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, random-forest

I would like to use the Random Forest method and look at the feature importance and prediction performance. However, my data is complex survey data, which has weights. Is there any way to consider the weights in modeling? Preferably to be coded in R or Python.

Comment: in theory, maybe. In practice, I doubt it (but good luck!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805192/scikit-learn-random-forest-class-weight-and-sample-weight-parameters